# Set 2 Adapters on a single ListView

Tags: android-animation, expandablelistview

I am working on a project which requires setting two adapters on a single ListView.

[ListViewAnimation](https://github.com/nhaarman/ListViewAnimations) AND [Android-SlideExpandableListView](https://github.com/tjerkw/Android-SlideExpandableListView)

How to do it?

Answer (score 0):

Try the `ExpandableListItemAdapter` in the ListViewAnimations library. That way you can stack two adapters:

```
ExpandableListItemAdapter eliAdapter = new ExpandableListItemAdapter(MainActivity.this){ /* implement required methods */};
SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter animAdapter = new SwingBottomInAnimationAdapter(eliAdapter);
animAdapter.setAbsListView(mListView);
mListView.setAdapter(animAdapter);
```